# Gtk-rs crashes gnomne session on async data fetch and assigning it to label on button click event

Tags: linux, gtk3, gnome, cairo, gtk-rs

Async data fetching from [this rest api](https://api.covid19api.com/summary) and setting it to as label in `gtk-rs` makes gnome-session crash.

To reproduce:

1. create a new cargo project
2. create svg files named `home.svg` and `about.svg`
3. create a css file named `main.css`

```css
#left_pane {
    background-color: #ff3551;
}
#left_pane button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}

#right_pane {
    background-color: #131313;
    font-size: 20px;
}

* {
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

4. Place the following dependencies in `cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
gtk = "0.9.2"
gdk = "0.13.2"
glib = "0.10.3"
gdk-pixbuf = "0.9.0"
async-std = "1.9.0"
reqwest = "0.11.2"
tokio = { version = "1.3.0", features = ["full"] }
```

5. copy and paste the following in `main.rs`

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::process::exit;
use std::rc::Rc;

use gdk_pixbuf::{Pixbuf, PixbufLoaderExt};
use gtk::{ButtonExt, ContainerExt, CssProvider, CssProviderExt, GtkWindowExt, Image, Label, Orientation, WidgetExt, WindowType, LabelExt};
use gtk::prelude::WidgetExtManual;
use glib;
use glib::Continue;
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::thread::Thread;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    gtk::init().unwrap();
    init_window();
    gtk::main();
}

fn init_css(win: &gtk::Window) {
    let css = CssProvider::new();
    css.load_from_path("main.css").unwrap();
    let screen = win.get_screen().unwrap();
    gtk::StyleContext::add_provider_for_screen(&screen, &css, gtk::STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
}

fn init_window() {
    let win = gtk::Window::new(WindowType::Toplevel);
    init_css(&win);
    win.set_title("Youtube Tutorial");
    win.connect_destroy(|_| exit(0));
    {
        let parent = gtk::Box::new(Orientation::Horizontal, 2);
        init_right_pane(&parent, init_left_pane(&parent));
        win.add(&parent);
    }
    win.show_all();
}

struct LeftPaneElements {
    home_bt: gtk::Button,
    about_bt: gtk::Button,
}

fn init_right_pane(parent: &gtk::Box, left_pane_elements: LeftPaneElements) {
    let right_pane = Rc::new(gtk::Box::new(Orientation::Horizontal, 1));
    right_pane.set_widget_name("right_pane");
    right_pane.set_hexpand(true);
    {
        let right_pane = right_pane.clone();
        left_pane_elements.home_bt.connect_clicked(move |_| {
            if let Some(s) = right_pane.get_children().get(0) {
                right_pane.remove(s);
            }
            let label = Rc::new(Label::new(Some("Home")));
            label.set_label("Fetching...");
            let (ready_tx, ready_rx) = glib::MainContext::channel(glib::PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
            tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap().block_on(async {
                println!("Thread name on async is {}", thread::current().name().unwrap_or("unknown"));
                let str = reqwest::get("https://api.covid19api.com/summary").await.unwrap().text().await.unwrap();
                ready_tx.send(str).unwrap();
            });
            label.set_visible(true);
            right_pane.add(label.deref());
            let label = label.clone();
            ready_rx.attach(None, move |str| {
                println!("Thread name on receiving {} is {}", str, thread::current().name().unwrap_or("unknown"));
                label.set_label(&format!(" {} ", str));
                Continue(true)
            });
        });
    }
    {
        let right_pane = right_pane.clone();
        left_pane_elements.about_bt.connect_clicked(move |_| {
            if let Some(s) = right_pane.get_children().get(0) {
                right_pane.remove(s);
            }
            let label = Label::new(Some("About"));
            label.set_visible(true);
            right_pane.add(&label);
        });
    }
    parent.add(right_pane.deref());
}

fn init_left_pane(parent: &gtk::Box) -> LeftPaneElements {
    let left_pane = gtk::Box::new(Orientation::Vertical, 4);
    left_pane.set_widget_name("left_pane");
    left_pane.set_property_width_request(50);
    {
        let space = gtk::Box::new(Orientation::Vertical, 0);
        space.set_vexpand(true);
        left_pane.add(&space);
    }
    let left_pane_elements = LeftPaneElements {
        home_bt: {
            let home_bt = gtk::Button::new();
            home_bt.set_image(Some(&Image::from_pixbuf(Some(&Pixbuf::from_file_at_scale("home.svg", 25, 25, true).unwrap()))));
            home_bt.set_size_request(50, 50);
            left_pane.add(&home_bt);
            home_bt
        },
        about_bt: {
            let about_bt = gtk::Button::new();
            about_bt.set_size_request(50, 50);
            about_bt.set_image(Some(&Image::from_pixbuf(Some(&Pixbuf::from_file_at_scale("about.svg", 25, 25, true).unwrap()))));
            left_pane.add(&about_bt);
            about_bt
        },
    };
    {
        let space = gtk::Box::new(Orientation::Vertical, 0);
        space.set_vexpand(true);
        left_pane.add(&space);
    }
    parent.add(&left_pane);
    left_pane_elements
}
```

6. Compile and run the program
7. Click on the home button in the left panel
8. Gnome shell crashes

The code works fine under `bspwm` and `Xephyr` using `Xephyr -br -ac -reset -softCursor -screen 1600x900 :2`.

The bug seems to resolve when the string is sliced using `&str[3..10]` on line number `68`. Seems to be an issue with backspace characters and their rendering in Cairo or might be an issue with the compositor. I can't think of a reason for the session to crash instead of the application.

`neofetch output`

```
██████████████████  ████████   aniketfuryrocks@manjaro
██████████████████  ████████   -----------------------
██████████████████  ████████   OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64
██████████████████  ████████   Host: 81BF Ideapad 520-15IKB
████████            ████████   Kernel: 5.11.2-1-MANJARO
████████  ████████  ████████   Uptime: 23 mins
████████  ████████  ████████   Packages: 1468 (pacman), 11 (flatpak), 5 (snap)
████████  ████████  ████████   Shell: zsh 5.8
████████  ████████  ████████   Resolution: 1600x900, 1920x1080
████████  ████████  ████████   DE: GNOME 3.38.3
████████  ████████  ████████   WM: Mutter
████████  ████████  ████████   WM Theme: Matcha-dark-sea
████████  ████████  ████████   Theme: Matcha-dark-sea [GTK2/3]
████████  ████████  ████████   Icons: Papirus-Dark-Maia [GTK2/3]
                               Terminal: alacritty
                               Terminal Font: black: '
                               CPU: Intel i5-8250U (8) @ 3.400GHz
                               GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620
                               GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX150
                               Memory: 4301MiB / 7865MiB
```

Comment: The API response appx `50,883` characters. Might be a buffer overflow issue with Cairo.

Comment: If Gnome-shell crashes, wouldn't that be a bug in Gnome-shell? According to https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell, bug reports go to https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues.

Comment: When I run and click that thing, it shows HTML code with `503 Service Temporary Unavailable` (but I am not using Gnome).

Comment: @UliSchlachter The API becomes unavailable on usage surge. Please try again later or try 2 -3 times. Try a wget to be sure.

Comment: @UliSchlachter after experimenting I came to the conclusion that the window expands too much horizontally to accommodate the label and therefore gnome-session could not handle it and crashes. I am using dual monitors with one in 1920x1080 and the other in 1600x900 resolution.